# I am new to LWC. I want to get all field values and show alert message on Rating field,

Tags: javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-web-components

**Here is my LWC**

```
@api recordId;
    account;
    lastModifiedDate;
    rating;
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (error) {
           console.log('error occured');
        } else if (data) {
            this.account = data;
            console.log('Log account>>>>>>', this.account);
            let modifiedDate=this.account.lastModifiedDate;
            let modifiedrate=getFieldValue(this.account, RATING_FIELD);
            console.log('Log modifiedrate>>>>>>', modifiedrate);
         /*   if(!this.rating)
            {
                this.rating=this.account.Rating;
                console.log('Console this.rating=this.account.Rating;',this.rating=this.account.Rating);
            }
            if(modifiedrate != Null && modifiedrate =='Hot')
            {
                alert('alert')
            }*/
            if(!this.lastModifiedDate) {
                this.lastModifiedDate = this.account.lastModifiedDate;
               console.log('Console lastmodified date---->',this.lastModifiedDate);
            }
            if (modifiedDate != this.lastModifiedDate) {
                console.log('Console modified date---->',this.lastModifiedDate);
                this.showNotification();
            }
        }
    }

    showNotification() {
        const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Account Updated',
            variant: 'success'
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
```

When I console modified rate to get Rating field value it displays null. Although in while consoling data Rating values are visible

Comment: Did you import RATING_FIELD like
`import RATING_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.YourRatingField';`?

Comment: Whenever you are accessing field data without "getFieldValue" you need to write it as "this.account.fields.Name.value" It must be causing issue at this line and hence modifiedRate is just coming as null